# How to make multiple objects not visible with multiple form events

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# windows form project with five read only text boxes.
When a box is clicked a textbox specific list box becomes visible for selection which closes once something is selected from that listbox and written to the textbox.
I have also been able to make it so that any open listboxes are not visible, if another textbox is selected.
What I need help with is how to make sure all listboxes are not visible if anything other than the textboxes on the form is selected eg buttons, other text boxes, menus etc.
I wondered if there was a more efficient way to do this than calling a method which ensures all listboxes are not visible, from every defined event on the form .
Thanks
Apologies  but should have entered more detail and oversimplified things.
In fact the text boxes activate panels with a list box and buttons which modify that listbox.
I have tried leave event handlers on both the panel and listbox but neither seem to work when you click anywhere other than the textboxes. If you put a leave event on the text boxes, you don't get the opportunity to select anything from the list box as the panel is closed.
Code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void textBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void textBox3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.Text = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void listBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void listBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void panel1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void panel2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again

Comment: You should share some of your code and what you have tried so far. Anyway, why don't you show and hide those listboxes in the `Enter` and `Leave` events of each textbox? These events don't work if the textbox is disabled, but they do if it's read-only.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use ComboBox? This do exactly what you want by default.

Comment: I have included more information in the question to clarify - apologies

Answer (score 0):

You can control the visibility of multiple `Control`s by binding their Visible property to a common variable. In the Visual Studio designer, select the textbox and look at its properties. There is a section labeled **DataBindings**, and under that an **(Advanced)** option. Click that, and you will see a list of properties available for binding. Select the Visibility property and choose an existing boolean variable (as a Project data source) to associate with it. You can use the same variable to bind to the Visibile property of several textboxes. When your program logic sets that variable to True or False, the group of textboxes should appear/disappear accordingly.

Comment: Thank you as that will simplify the code significantly. Would that not mean though that I would have to introduce a line of code into all other events on the form to switch the variable to false, closing in this example the two panels? Just wondered if there was an easier way? Effectively I want to be able to make sure the panels in this case are not visible when I click on one of the buttons or anything else on the form.

Comment: It depends - when you say "all other events on the form", what are you actually responding to? Do these other panels display information to help the user make their selection, or are they responding to what the user has chosen?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have sorted a solution as described above. I simply wanted the panels to become non visible in case the user went to another part of the form, and one of the panels was still open.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have in fact solved this with a bit of perseverence
To précis, two textboxes open individual panels with buttons and a listbox. Buttons within the panel will modify the listbox and when a selection is made in the listbox it is written to the same read only textbox. My problem was I needed to have these panels close if a selection was not made and a user went to another part of the form.
I have tried all combinations, and the solution seems to be to set focus on the panel when it is opened by textbox click event, and then have a panel leave event which makes the panel not visible. I also needed to make panels non visible with a form click event.
The final code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void textBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel1.Focus();
        }

        private void textBox3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
            panel2.Focus();
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.Text = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }      

        private void panel1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void panel2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```